# Is it the right way to use wildcard instead of variables in makefile?

Tags: makefile

My current `Makefile` is like the following:

```
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%, $(BUILDDIR)/%, $(SRC_FILES:.cpp=.o))

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp              # <----------- HERE
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

It feels very strange to me that, on the one hand `OBJ_FILES` is defined and `$(TARGET)` does depend on it, on the other hand `OBJ_FILES` doesn't have a "rule". In fact object files are compiled according to a wildcard matching rule, as is marked by `HERE` in code above.

Is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: This is an entirely reasonable way to construct a makefile. Why do you feel like it isn't? You **could** limit that rule to just the contents of `$(OBJ_FILES)` by making it a [Static Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) but that won't really do anything for you.